# .JSON file creates NULL value via PHP

Tags: php, json

So I'm trying to figure out why I get a NULL value in my .json file after I try to write the array to it. It only happens with the 'array_push' line after creating a new file. If there is a .json file already there with a value in it, it'll write to it correctly. The only thing I could guess was the file is missing the '{' and '}' in it upon creation.

I've got a small work around so far, but not sure that this is the right way to do it. Can someone tell me if this is good or bad?

Just to clarify, the .json document only holds the vault of NULL, there are no array elements or anything in the file besides the word NULL.

```
//CHECK IF FILE EXISTS, ELSE CREATE IT
$log_filename = "./site_files/logs/error-404-log.json";
if(!file_exists($log_filename)) {
    touch($log_filename);
    //LINE BELOW IS MY WORK AROUND, I'M NOT SURE IF THIS IS THE RIGHT WAY
    file_put_contents($log_filename, json_encode(json_decode("{}")));
    echo "$log_filename was created. <br />";
}

$log_array = array();
$new_data =  array(
    'current_date_stamp' => $current_date_stamp,
    'current_page_trail' => $current_page_trail
);

$json_data = file_get_contents($log_filename);
if($log_array != "") { $log_array = json_decode($json_data, true); }
//WHEN CREATING A NEW FILE, ARRAY_PUSH GIVES ERROR
array_push($log_array, $new_data);
$json_data = json_encode($log_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

file_put_contents($log_filename, $json_data);
```

Comment: Would you care to share the error message? It will typically tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Why are you comparing an array to an empty string? And if you're getting null back from json_encode you may want to do some error checking. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$log_filename = "error-404-log.json";                // establish the path/to/filename.json
if (file_exists($log_filename)) {                    // if path/to/filename.json exists
    $json = file_get_contents($log_filename);        // access PRETTY json string
    echo "pre-existing data: <div><pre>$json</pre></div><br>";  // display json string
    $array = json_decode($json, true);               // decode to prepare for new data
}

// data always maintains the same structure: an array of 2-element arrays
$array[] = [
    'current_date_stamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'current_page_trail' => "foo"
];

// create/update the file
$new_json = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);  // re-encode updated array data
echo "new data: <div><pre>$new_json</pre></div>";    // display new json string
file_put_contents($log_filename, $new_json);         // create or overwrite file
```

Comment: (I've tested this to be successful on my localhost)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I tested it a few times and everything came back gold. Thank you!

Comment: Do you by chance know how to pull each item out of the array from the .json file?

Comment: Once the json is decoded (converted to an array), you can use a loop to iterate the subarrays.  What kind of interaction did you want to do with the data? Depending on your intent, the structure of the json could be improved.

Comment: Because the datetime stamp is going to be unique, you _could_ just make a 1-dim associative array like: `$array[date('Y-m-d H:i:s')] = "foo";` The data storage design depends on how you intend to use the data. (Purpose-build data storage)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because you are comparing `$log_array` with an empty string, this condition will **always** pass because this array will never be an empty string. In the if statement you decode the contents of the file, when the file has no content this will be an empty string and it will return `NULL`, after this you write this `NULL` value to your file. If you check if `$json_data` is an empty string your code should work, I would also recommend doing it like this:

```
$log_array = array();
$new_data =  array(
 'current_date_stamp' => $current_date_stamp,
 'current_page_trail' => $current_page_trail
);

$json_data = file_get_contents($log_filename);
if($json_data != "") { 
    $log_array = json_decode($json_data, true); 
    //WHEN CREATING A NEW FILE, ARRAY_PUSH GIVES ERROR
    array_push($log_array, $new_data);
    $json_data = json_encode($log_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    file_put_contents($log_filename, $json_data);
}
```

This is better since if the string is empty all other actions are irrelevant.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't run. I even tried adding a extra step to it.

if(($json_data != "") && ($json_data != " ")) {
//Code
}

Comment: Could you elobarte on what 'didn't run?' what error did you get @logicK